# How to extract multiple strings from identical id's using Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I wrote this bit of code in order to extract the id's and roll's from a website.

```
import requests
import json
import time
import urllib


def ColorRequest(a=True):
url = 'http://csgoroll.com/v1/roulette/state?token=bcb7841fe779ac0ae2a9e4f882ed3961ce0d714215fede3c025a24fc418e123dcb5a0a47a0ba1825225c14b39e08ea399422eb2b012689a79c41f42b529640e37d5374125c3fef409b2d165c223923dbc27f320c53bf10e46e701058251c97b9'  # Could add a + pls str(pagesomething) to add on to the url so that it would update
sourcecode = requests.get(url)  # requests the data from the site
plaintext = sourcecode.text  # imports all of the data gathered

obj = json.loads(plaintext)
for roll in obj['rolls']:

    print(roll['id'], roll['roll'])
    while a == True:
        ColorRequest()
        time.sleep(1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
ColorRequest()
```

But the data looks like this

```
{
"gameState": 
"1",
"currentGame": "9965464",
"startDate": "Mon Dec 05 2016 23:30:42 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
"rolls": [
    {
        "id": 9965465,
        "hash": "f39a2391bd589fc217b73c407e316ff440dc920657929bd7ca9b7adddf0cedc9",
        "roll": 11,
        "state": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9965466,
        "hash": "45eaa2bddb3281f036932de5839d4ccc2b28ebb1d4ded8f6e67cbff273831c73",
        "roll": 3,
        "state": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9965467,
        "hash": "b6142c643816d2913a29518fdf624fcf577397af4ebfb008d61c4f1cf9d6ba3e",
        "roll": 1,
        "state": 3,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
```

My question is how do I get my program to recognize that there is multiple layers of data for it to read and store it, so far it will only grab the top result and contain it at run time.

Comment: what is `layer` ? `rolls` ? `len(obj['rolls'])` ? There are no indentical `id`s. BTW `obj = sourcecode.json()`

Comment: It's not clear what you want: your code currently enters a recursive loop after it prints the first `roll`. That seems completely unnecessary. So, what is that you want to achieve? Make a request and then print all `roll` data? And once done repeat this every say 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

Check the len(rolls) to make sure is at least 1 and then just set the value of the 1st element for example top_id = obj['rolls'][0]['id'] or top_state = obj['rolls'][0]['state'] hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, all you want to do is repeat the loop every 1000 seconds, and at each iteration print all data in the `rolls`.

```
import requests
import time

def ColorRequest():
    url = 'http://csgoroll.com/v1/roulette/state?token=bcb7841fe779ac0ae2a9e4f882ed3961ce0d714215fede3c025a24fc418e123dcb5a0a47a0ba1825225c14b39e08ea399422eb2b012689a79c41f42b529640e37d5374125c3fef409b2d165c223923dbc27f320c53bf10e46e701058251c97b9'  # Could add a + pls str(pagesomething) to add on to the url so that it would update
    sourcecode = requests.get(url)  # requests the data from the site
    obj = sourcecode.json()
    for roll in obj['rolls']:
        print(roll['id'], roll['roll'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        ColorRequest()
        time.sleep(1000)   # these are seconds, ~17min
```